# For each ID, drop a row based on its relationship to another row: the order of occurrence (date) and duplicated value of a variable Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have an example DataFrame below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 1,'2016-09-01','pay',1], [1, 2, 1, '2016-09-01','claims',1], [2, 3, 3, '2016-09-02','claims',1],[2,4,3,'2016-10-02','pay',2],[3,5,4,'2016-09-02','pay',1],[3,6,5,'2016-09-04','pay',2],[3,7,4,'2016-09-06','claims',3],[3,8,6,'2016-09-08','pay',4]], columns=['claim_id', 'payment_id', 'provider_id','date','dataset','date_rank'])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']) # this column ought to be date
df
```

[df image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXU8F.png)

There are duplicate payments that cannot be removed using a simple drop_duplicates() because the decision to drop a row or not depends on it's relationship to other payment rows of the same claim_id.

I would like to create a new column called 'dup' which labels the rows that are duplicates so that I can review them before dropping them from the DataFrame.

The logic needed to accurately remove the duplicates is:

For each claim_id in df:
For the payment where df['dataset'] == 'claims', check if there is another payment for the same claim_id that has the same provider_id and that occurs prior to or on the same df['date']. If there is, label the new column df['dup'] as True for the payment where df['dataset'] == 'claims'. Otherwise, label the new column df['dup'] as False.

In this example, payment_id's 2 and 7 should have a value of True in the new column 'dup' while all other payment id's should be False:

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 1,'2016-09-01','pay',1,False], [1, 2, 1, '2016-09-01','claims',1,True], [2, 3, 3, '2016-09-02','claims',1,False],[2,4,3,'2016-10-02','pay',2,False],[3,5,4,'2016-09-02','pay',1,False],[3,6,5,'2016-09-04','pay',2,False],[3,7,4,'2016-09-06','claims',3,True],[3,8,6,'2016-09-08','pay',4,False]], columns=['claim_id', 'payment_id', 'provider_id','date','dataset','date_rank','dup'])
df_out['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_out['date']) # this column ought to be date
df_out
```

[df_out image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSQH4.png)

I have tried many different things including trying to break this down into steps but have not been successful. In one of these attempts I created the date_rank column which labels the payments by the date order that they appear. I have included this here in case it is helpful.

Comment: can you explain again why payment_id's 2 and 7 are true? what is the "duplicated" row?

Comment: Only 'claims' dataset rows can be duplicates. payment_id 2 is a duplicate of payment_id 1 bc it comes from the claims dataset, has the same claim_id, provider_id AND same date as payment_id 1. payment_id 7 is a duplicate of payment_id 5 bc it comes from the claims dataset, has the same claim_id, provider_id AND has a later date than payment_id 5. payment_id 3 is not a duplicate of payment_id 4 bc even though it is from the claims dataset, has the same claim_id and provider_id as payment_id 4, the date occurs prior to payment_id 4's date. Did that answer your question? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

it's a little bit ugly but it works

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 1,'2016-09-01','pay',1], [1, 2, 1, '2016-09-01','claims',1], [2, 3, 3, '2016-09-02','claims',1],[2,4,3,'2016-10-02','pay',2],[3,5,4,'2016-09-02','pay',1],[3,6,5,'2016-09-04','pay',2],[3,7,4,'2016-09-06','claims',3],[3,8,6,'2016-09-08','pay',4]], columns=['claim_id', 'payment_id', 'provider_id','date','dataset','date_rank'])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']) # this column ought to be date



df['dup'] = False
provider_list = list(set(df['provider_id'].tolist()))
for provider in provider_list:
  temp_df = df.loc[df['provider_id'] == provider]
  claim_list = list(set(df['claim_id'].tolist()))
  for claim in claim_list:
      temp_df2 = temp_df.loc[temp_df['claim_id'] == claim]
      if len(set(temp_df2['dataset'].tolist())) == 2:
        pay_date = temp_df2.loc[temp_df2['dataset'] == 'pay', 'date'].iloc[0]
        claim_date = temp_df2.loc[temp_df2['dataset'] == 'claims', 'date'].iloc[0]
        if pay_date <= claim_date:
          payment_id = temp_df2.loc[temp_df2['dataset'] == 'claims', 'payment_id'].iloc[0]
          df.loc[df['payment_id'] == payment_id, 'dup'] = True
      else:
        continue
df
```

output:

```
    claim_id    payment_id  provider_id date    dataset date_rank   dup
0      1           1           1       2016-09-01   pay     1       False
1      1           2           1       2016-09-01   claims  1       True
2      2           3           3       2016-09-02   claims  1       False
3      2           4           3       2016-10-02   pay     2       False
4      3           5           4       2016-09-02   pay     1       False
5      3           6           5       2016-09-04   pay     2       False
6      3           7           4       2016-09-06   claims  3       True
7      3           8           6      2016-09-08    pay     4       False
```

***EDIT***
because you have to iterate each `provider_id` (I didn't find a different way) and you have more then 1M rows, I recommend to split the `DataFrame` into chunks of ~1000.
In addition, I would save the result as csv file for each chunk just in case the run will collapse (in that case I would continue from the place it collapsed)

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools

chunk_n = 1000
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 1,'2016-09-01','pay',1], [1, 2, 1, '2016-09-01','claims',1], [2, 3, 3, '2016-09-02','claims',1],[2,4,3,'2016-10-02','pay',2],[3,5,4,'2016-09-02','pay',1],[3,6,5,'2016-09-04','pay',2],[3,7,4,'2016-09-06','claims',3],[3,8,6,'2016-09-08','pay',4]], columns=['claim_id', 'payment_id', 'provider_id','date','dataset','date_rank'])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']) # this column ought to be date
df['dup'] = False
list_of_df = []

provider_list = list(set(df['provider_id'].tolist()))
provider_groups = [list(group) for key, group in itertools.groupby(provider_list, lambda k: k//chunk_n)]
i = 0
for group in provider_groups:
  print('starting group', i)
  temp_df = df.loc[df['provider_id'].isin(group)]
  for provider in group:
    claim_list = list(set(temp_df.loc[temp_df['provider_id'] == provider, 'claim_id'].tolist()))  
    for claim in claim_list:
        temp_df2 = temp_df.loc[(temp_df['claim_id'] == claim) & (temp_df['provider_id'] == provider)]
        if len(set(temp_df2['dataset'].tolist())) == 2:
          pay_date = temp_df2.loc[temp_df2['dataset'] == 'pay', 'date'].iloc[0]
          claim_date = temp_df2.loc[temp_df2['dataset'] == 'claims', 'date'].iloc[0]
          if pay_date <= claim_date:
            payment_id = temp_df2.loc[temp_df2['dataset'] == 'claims', 'payment_id'].iloc[0]
            temp_df.loc[temp_df['payment_id'] == payment_id, 'dup'] = True
        else:
          continue
  list_of_df.append(temp_df)
  # temp_df.to_csv('group_{}.csv'.format(i))
  # i += 1


df = pd.concat(list_of_df)
```

Comment: Dean, this worked perfectly! Thank you very much and I will also take the time to learn from your code.

Comment: Happy to help! please note that you can do it in a better way in less lines, but this is the intuetive way level by level. In addition I will appreciate if you vote on my answer and accept my answer as a solution, Thanks!

Comment: Hi Dean, I am having trouble running it on my actual data set that is approximately 1million rows in size. The code has been running for a very long time with no output. Do you have any suggestions that could help? I upvoted the answer but because I am new to Stack Overflow I don't have enough reputation points for it to appear as upvoted but it did say that the feedback was recorded. Cheers!